# How To Monitor Contents Of Folder Without Blocking Finder

Tags: applescript, desktop, finder

As you can see from my code below I am extremely new to this. My code just about works, but my major issue is that it hogs up Finder and sometimes it does not set the Desktop picture, but does most of the time!

The script just monitors a folder, and if an "***.jpg" is added then the Desktop picture set to it.

This is my very first script so I have a lot to learn,

```
set reset to ""
display notification "Alarm Front Active  " & (current date) as string
tell application "Finder"
    set path_to_sourceFull to ":photo:FRONT CAM 1:20190929:images" -- from nsa310 network drive
    set path_to_source to ":photo:FRONT CAM 1:20190929:images" -- from nsa310 network drive
    set directory1 to "/Volumes/photo/FRONT CAM 1/20190929/images" as text -- from nsa310 network drive 
    set path_to_destinationFull to "Macintosh HD:Users:rekordbox:Documents:temp folder 2"
    set path_to_destination to ":Users:rekordbox:Documents:temp folder 2"
    set directory2 to "/Users/rekordbox/Documents/temp folder 2" as text

    repeat while reset = ""
        set allok to ""
        set filelist to name of every item in folder path_to_source --of startup disk       
        set listSizesaved to count of filelist
        delay 1

        repeat while allok = ""
            set filelist to name of every item in folder path_to_source --of startup disk           
            set listSize to count of filelist
            if listSize = listSizesaved then
            else
                set filelist to name of every item in folder path_to_source --of startup disk
                set listSize to count of filelist
                set LastAddedFile to item listSize of filelist
                set allok to "ALARM"
                set listSizesaved to listSize -- (save the updated) count               
                set activefile to (path_to_source & LastAddedFile)
                set selectedpicture to (directory1 & "/" & LastAddedFile)
                tell application "System Events" to tell every desktop to set picture to selectedpicture
                delay 1
                display notification "ALARM FRONT TRIGGERED...." & (current date) as string
                delay 1
            end if
        end repeat
    end repeat

end tell
```

Comment: Polling with infinite repeat loops is really expensive. You are strongly discouraged from doing that. A better way is a Folder Action

Answer (score 1):

The script you want, I think, is this:

```
on adding folder items to thisFolder after receiving filelist
    set droppedFile to first item of filelist

    tell application "System Events"
        tell every desktop
            set picture to droppedFile
        end tell
    end tell
end adding folder items to
```

(I've left out the 'Alarm' bit, since I wasn't sure what the point of it was.)

To use this script, copy it into Script Editor, save it in the folder `~/Library/Scripts/Folder Action Scripts/`, then open the applet 'Folder Actions Setup'. Add the folder you want on the left-hand side, and choose the file you just saved on the right. It should look something like this:
[image]
...where the checkmark on the left shows that folder actions are enabled for the folder (which I called 'test folder') and the script (which I called 'FADtop.scpt') is attached.

Drop an image in the folder, and it should just work.

As a general rule, don't script the Finder unless you absolutely need to; always use System Events. The Finder is a busy app, and scripting it can gum up the system. And also try to avoid this design pattern:

```
(* Don't do this! *)
repeat 
    (* test for something *)
    delay x
end
```

The `delay` command is not particularly resource-efficient. If you really want to use a polling system to test for some event, it's often better to create a stand-alone app with an `on idle` handler. That way you let the system wake and sleep the script, with significant performance improvements.

**EDIT**

Since folder actions don't seem to be working with ftp drops onto remote drives, here's a reasonably efficient folder-polling approach. Save the following script as a stay-open application (choose 'Application' as the file type, and click the 'stay open' checkbox). Then launch the application and leave it running in the background.

```
property dateOfLastFileChosen : missing value
property targetFolder : "/Volumes/photo/FRONT CAM 1/20190929/images"
property idleTime : 300 -- 300 seconds is five minutes

on run
end run

on idle
    tell application "System Events"
        if exists folder targetFolder then
            if dateOfLastFileChosen is missing value then
                set recentFiles to every file of folder targetFolder whose visible is true
            else
                set recentFiles to every file of folder targetFolder whose modification date > dateOfLastFileChosen and visible is true
            end if

            set newFile to my mostRecentFileOfList(recentFiles)
            if newFile is not missing value then
                set dateOfLastFileChosen to modification date of newFile
                tell every desktop
                    set picture to (POSIX path of newFile)
                end tell
            end if
        end if
    end tell

    return idleTime -- check every 5 minutes (300 seconds)
end idle

on mostRecentFileOfList(fileList)
    set maxDateObj to missing value
    repeat with thisFile in fileList
        if maxDateObj is missing value then
            set maxDateObj to contents of thisFile
        else if modification date of thisFile is greater than modification date of maxDateObj then
            set maxDateObj to thisFile
        end if
    end repeat
    return maxDateObj
end mostRecentFileOfList
```

Comment: Ted Wrigley.... WOW it looks great and its exactly what i wanted.. So can i first say thank you. However i am getting an issue so i hope you wouldn't mind giving me a little more help.. Your script works well when i use folders on my mac but when i do the same and attach it to a drive on my network it don't work.. I've tried to allow Guest with no password at the moment just to test...

Comment: From what I understand, folder actions *ought* to work over network drives, but whenever the network drive is unmounted it disables the folder action (which then needs to be restarted). that's scriptable, but unfortunately I don't have a network drive to test on. You may also be running into security issues if you have access set to 'Guest'. It might turn out to be more effective to use a launch agent for this, but see if you can get the folder action to work first

Comment: From what i can see the folder name changes to Red Colour Font on the left hand side of the folder action setup.

Comment: I've never seen that, but it doesn't sound hopeful. What kind of share is it, NAS? Give me a day or so and I'll write up an alternative (a bit busy at the moment, sorry...) By the way, is there a reason you have to have the drop folder on a remote drive? why not put it in your local volume and drag the file from the network to there?

Comment: The cameras record directly to it the drive, over wise I would have to leave my mac on also if the mac was stolen I would have no recordings. Unless I sent the to the cloud

Comment: I have wrote another script which logins in to the network drive. Now it isn’t Red anymore... it has worked when I first connect but only the one file.. it’s like it’s just not monitoring the folder all the time. The connection is hard wired so it shouldn’t loose connection

Comment: It's possible the drive is going to sleep in the interim, which might disrupt the folder action. Let me think on that a bit...

Comment: Hi @ted wrigley  I’m away for a couple of days but I don’t think that is the case as it’s being written to constantly 24/7 from the cameras, also I’ve be doing stuff between the mac and the drive at the same time as is meant to be monitoring.

Comment: UPDATE.. i've found that if i manually drop the pictures into the network folder being monitored it works but not when the folder receives the picture from a it ftp source  any ideas...

Comment: Your camera is sending the pictures to the drive directly via ftp? What a setup... Well, apparently the system is not registering the ftp download as an added item (possibly because it bypasses the normal system move/copy routines, and isn't triggering the notifications that Folder actions look for?). At any rate, I'll edit in an alternate approach, you can see if you have more success with that.

Comment: I think it's only fair if I give you a +1  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Without trying to steal the thunder from @Ted Wrigley, whose solution provided the AppleScript code for the folder action,  I felt there were enough comments and items for me to add to post it as another answer to the OP's dilemma.

First I will address the `tell every desktop` `set picture to droppedFile` lines of code in the following AppleScript Folder Action.  If the user has only one monitor/display attached to the computer, but has created several different "Spaces", the `tell every desktop` `set picture to droppedFile` lines of code will only change the Desktop Picture for the Desktop of the current active "Space" only. The other Desktop backgrounds will not be changed.  However, if the user has several monitors/displays attached to the computer, the `tell every desktop` `set picture to droppedFile` lines of code will change the Desktop Pictures for the Desktops of the current active "Space" for each attached monitor/display.  If the latter is not the desired result, then `tell every desktop` should be changed to `tell current desktop`.

After testing the AppleScript Folder Action code provided by @Ted Wrigley, I noticed the image file being downloaded from an FTP server, to the test folder where I have the folder action script attached to, looked like this before the image was actually finished transferring. Because the file was kind of there and not there, it did not trigger the Folder Action.

[image]

Next, I figured I would add a delay to be beginning of the Folder Action code to allow for the transfer of the image file from the FTP server, to complete.  I added a delay of 180 seconds to allow for the transfer to complete and it worked. When the transfer was complete, the file look like this.

[image]

Depending on how many files you foresee being transferred at any given time along with factoring in for file sizes...  It's possible you may need to significantly increase the Delay time.

```
on adding folder items to thisFolder after receiving theseFiles
    delay 180
    set newBackground to first item of theseFiles

    tell application "System Events"
        set picture of current desktop to newBackground -- Single Display Attached
        --set picture of every desktop to newBackground -- Multiple Displays Attached
    end tell
end adding folder items to
```

Comment: Please, feel free to steal my thunder anytime. I like the quiet life.  

Comment: thank you @wch1zpink your explanation to what’s going on is much appreciated.  Your addition has worked.  Been pulling my hair out on this as I can never give up.  It all makes sense now.  I have a lot to learn so thank you and ted for your time you’ve gave me..

Comment: @petethebigineer  You're welcome. We are more than happy to help. However, the proper way to thank someone, if their solutions have helped, is to upvote their answer and to mark the post which actually solved your problem, as the accepted answer.

Comment: i'm looking for an icon to upvote your answers and to mark the post but i can't see how to do it :)

Comment: Just to the left of the Beginning of every post, There is an up arrow and a number and a down arrow...